# how to give object class to the function

Tags: typescript, oop

Here is the code
[image]

copy-pasted code:

```
const check = async <Entity>(

      ) => {
        if (ObjectUtil.areChanged(memberUser.client, data, 'employmentTypeId')) {
          const beforeEmploymentType = await manager.findOneOrFail(Entity, memberUser.client.employmentTypeId);
          const afterEmploymentType = await manager.findOneOrFail(EmploymentType, data.employmentTypeId);
        }
      }
```

How can I add **any object class** to the function? It gives `'Entity' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is needed to add EntityTarget to implement any Entity class, it looks like:

```
const check = async <Entity, A>(
    manager: EntityManager,
    entity: EntityTarget<Entity>,
    base: A,
    key: keyof A,
) => {
  const beforeEntity = await manager.findOneOrFail(entity, base[key]);
};
```

So the using would be

```
await check(manager, Room, booking, 'roomId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all types are erased after compilation, and so are type parameters (`<Entity>`), there's no such thing as `Entity` at runtime, so you cannot use it anywhere but in type annotations.

You need to pass it as a value to your function, like this:

```js
const check = async (Entity: ???) => { ... }
```

I can't figure out a type for `Entity` parameter, because I cannot really tell what it is and how it's used from your example, but you can look for constructs like `typeof MyClass` to pass a class itself as a parameter, or `{ new(): MyClassInstance }` for just something that can be called with `new` keyword. I've made some examples [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiB2AXAlogntA3gKGn6ADgE7IBuYiAptPGALbUC80A5CwNzYC%2022okMAMIALZCAAmCFOmiUAHlXjiYU1Bhz5CJclWjBRE6M0REArpU49sAM1PxgKAPbxoVCIgAUsAFyu0BSkdrOCQ1AEosKzdPVXQwzmiPETFJULjOGzsHZGdXSncAJi9fTBpKAHcPMN9YjC4IzCj8xCLa%20OxoouSJNs4gA).